# BLAST database error: no alias or index file found for nucleotide database [swissprot] in search path

Tags: perl, blast

I am following this link: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK52637/

I install NCBI BLAST+ package. Then create db folder inside blast-2.2.31+ folder to download one of NCBI databases. I select swissprot database and download it in the db folder. After that, I run:

perl update_blastdb.pl --passive swissprot

and it connect to NCBI successfully and download swissport in the bin folder. So, now I have two swissprot.tar.gz. One I download it in db folder and one downloaded in bin folder after running perl cammand.

Then I set PATH and BLASTDB environment variables. **BLASTDB will contain which swissport database? the one in db or in bin?**

***The main issue appears when I type:***
blastdbcmd -db swissprot -info

BLAST database error: no alias or index file found for nucleotide database [swissprot] in search path.....

What does this means?
I follow the link step by step.

Any hints?

Thank you and regards,,,
Alaa

Comment: This question appears to be related to a fairly specialized bioinformatics tool, which means you might be better off seeking help from people who are more familiar with it. There's a `blast-help` mailing list mentioned on the page you linked to---I'd give that a shot if I were you.